# Socket.emit cannot trigger socket.on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using Socket.io to create a simple application. To test if the client side and the server side are working correctly I use `socket.emit` to send message to the server and `socket.on` to write the message on the server console.

Now, I have been able to connect the client side to the server side by writing something on the console when the client is connected. But my issue is when I tried to send (`socket.emit`) data to the server, the `socket.on` method is not triggered. It doesn't give any errors as well.

Below is snippet of my codes

**Client Side --index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>

          <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>

        <script socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="socket.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script>


  $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

      </head>
    <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>

    </html>
```

**socket.io.js**

```
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{var f;"undefined"!=typeof window?f=window:"undefined"!=typeof global?f=global:"undefined"!=typeof self&&(f=self),f.io=e()}}(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){

module.exports = _dereq_('./lib/');

},{"./lib/":2}],2:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var url = _dereq_('./url');
var parser = _dereq_('socket.io-parser');
var Manager = _dereq_('./manager');
var debug = _dereq_('debug')('socket.io-client');

/**
 * Module exports.
 */

module.exports = exports = lookup;

/**
 * Managers cache.
 */

var cache = exports.managers = {};

/**
 * Looks up an existing `Manager` for multiplexing.
 * If the user summons:
 *
 *   `io('http://localhost/a');`
 *   `io('http://localhost/b');`
 *
 * We reuse the existing instance based on same scheme/port/host,
 * and we initialize sockets for each namespace.
 *
 * @api public
 */

function lookup(uri, opts) {
  if (typeof uri == 'object') {
    opts = uri;
    uri = undefined;
  }

  opts = opts || {};

  var parsed = url(uri);
  var source = parsed.source;
  var id = parsed.id;
  var path = parsed.path;
  var sameNamespace = (cache[id] && cache[id].nsps[path] &&
                      path == cache[id].nsps[path].nsp);
  var newConnection = opts.forceNew || opts['force new connection'] ||
                      false === opts.multiplex || sameNamespace;

  var io;

  if (newConnection) {
    debug('ignoring socket cache for %s', source);
    io = Manager(source, opts);
  } else {
    if (!cache[id]) {
      debug('new io instance for %s', source);
      cache[id] = Manager(source, opts);
    }
    io = cache[id];
  }

  return io.socket(parsed.path);
}

/**
 * Protocol version.
 *
 * @api public
 */

exports.protocol = parser.protocol;

/**
 * `connect`.
 *
 * @param {String} uri
 * @api public
 */

exports.connect = lookup;

/**
 * Expose constructors for standalone build.
 *
 * @api public
 */

exports.Manager = _dereq_('./manager');
exports.Socket = _dereq_('./socket');

},{"./manager":3,"./socket":5,"./url":6,"debug":10,"socket.io-parser":44}],3:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var url = _dereq_('./url');
var eio = _dereq_('engine.io-client');
var Socket = _dereq_('./socket');
var Emitter = _dereq_('component-emitter');
var parser = _dereq_('socket.io-parser');
var on = _dereq_('./on');
var bind = _dereq_('component-bind');
var object = _dereq_('object-component');
var debug = _dereq_('debug')('socket.io-client:manager');
var indexOf = _dereq_('indexof');
var Backoff = _dereq_('backo2');

/**
 * Module exports
 */

module.exports = Manager;

/**
 * `Manager` constructor.
 *
 * @param {String} engine instance or engine uri/opts
 * @param {Object} options
 * @api public
 */

function Manager(uri, opts){
  if (!(this instanceof Manager)) return new Manager(uri, opts);
  if (uri && ('object' == typeof uri)) {
    opts = uri;
    uri = undefined;
  }
  opts = opts || {};

  opts.path = opts.path || '/socket.io';
  this.nsps = {};
  this.subs = [];
  this.opts = opts;
  this.reconnection(opts.reconnection !== false);
  this.reconnectionAttempts(opts.reconnectionAttempts || Infinity);
  this.reconnectionDelay(opts.reconnectionDelay || 1000);
  this.reconnectionDelayMax(opts.reconnectionDelayMax || 5000);
  this.randomizationFactor(opts.randomizationFactor || 0.5);
  this.backoff = new Backoff({
    min: this.reconnectionDelay(),
    max: this.reconnectionDelayMax(),
    jitter: this.randomizationFactor()
  });
  this.timeout(null == opts.timeout ? 20000 : opts.timeout);
  this.readyState = 'closed';
  this.uri = uri;
  this.connected = [];
  this.encoding = false;
  this.packetBuffer = [];
  this.encoder = new parser.Encoder();
  this.decoder = new parser.Decoder();
  this.autoConnect = opts.autoConnect !== false;
  if (this.autoConnect) this.open();
}

/**
 * Propagate given event to sockets and emit on `this`
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.emitAll = function() {
  this.emit.apply(this, arguments);
  for (var nsp in this.nsps) {
    this.nsps[nsp].emit.apply(this.nsps[nsp], arguments);
  }
};

/**
 * Update `socket.id` of all sockets
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.updateSocketIds = function(){
  for (var nsp in this.nsps) {
    this.nsps[nsp].id = this.engine.id;
  }
};

/**
 * Mix in `Emitter`.
 */

Emitter(Manager.prototype);

/**
 * Sets the `reconnection` config.
 *
 * @param {Boolean} true/false if it should automatically reconnect
 * @return {Manager} self or value
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.reconnection = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._reconnection;
  this._reconnection = !!v;
  return this;
};

/**
 * Sets the reconnection attempts config.
 *
 * @param {Number} max reconnection attempts before giving up
 * @return {Manager} self or value
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.reconnectionAttempts = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._reconnectionAttempts;
  this._reconnectionAttempts = v;
  return this;
};

/**
 * Sets the delay between reconnections.
 *
 * @param {Number} delay
 * @return {Manager} self or value
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.reconnectionDelay = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._reconnectionDelay;
  this._reconnectionDelay = v;
  this.backoff && this.backoff.setMin(v);
  return this;
};

Manager.prototype.randomizationFactor = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._randomizationFactor;
  this._randomizationFactor = v;
  this.backoff && this.backoff.setJitter(v);
  return this;
};

/**
 * Sets the maximum delay between reconnections.
 *
 * @param {Number} delay
 * @return {Manager} self or value
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.reconnectionDelayMax = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._reconnectionDelayMax;
  this._reconnectionDelayMax = v;
  this.backoff && this.backoff.setMax(v);
  return this;
};

/**
 * Sets the connection timeout. `false` to disable
 *
 * @return {Manager} self or value
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.timeout = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._timeout;
  this._timeout = v;
  return this;
};

/**
 * Starts trying to reconnect if reconnection is enabled and we have not
 * started reconnecting yet
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.maybeReconnectOnOpen = function() {
  // Only try to reconnect if it's the first time we're connecting
  if (!this.reconnecting && this._reconnection && this.backoff.attempts === 0) {
    // keeps reconnection from firing twice for the same reconnection loop
    this.reconnect();
  }
};


/**
 * Sets the current transport `socket`.
 *
 * @param {Function} optional, callback
 * @return {Manager} self
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.open =
Manager.prototype.connect = function(fn){
  debug('readyState %s', this.readyState);
  if (~this.readyState.indexOf('open')) return this;

  debug('opening %s', this.uri);
  this.engine = eio(this.uri, this.opts);
  var socket = this.engine;
  var self = this;
  this.readyState = 'opening';
  this.skipReconnect = false;

  // emit `open`
  var openSub = on(socket, 'open', function() {
    self.onopen();
    fn && fn();
  });

  // emit `connect_error`
  var errorSub = on(socket, 'error', function(data){
    debug('connect_error');
    self.cleanup();
    self.readyState = 'closed';
    self.emitAll('connect_error', data);
    if (fn) {
      var err = new Error('Connection error');
      err.data = data;
      fn(err);
    } else {
      // Only do this if there is no fn to handle the error
      self.maybeReconnectOnOpen();
    }
  });

  // emit `connect_timeout`
  if (false !== this._timeout) {
    var timeout = this._timeout;
    debug('connect attempt will timeout after %d', timeout);

    // set timer
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
      debug('connect attempt timed out after %d', timeout);
      openSub.destroy();
      socket.close();
      socket.emit('error', 'timeout');
      self.emitAll('connect_timeout', timeout);
    }, timeout);

    this.subs.push({
      destroy: function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
    });
  }

  this.subs.push(openSub);
  this.subs.push(errorSub);

  return this;
};

/**
 * Called upon transport open.
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.onopen = function(){
  debug('open');

  // clear old subs
  this.cleanup();

  // mark as open
  this.readyState = 'open';
  this.emit('open');

  // add new subs
  var socket = this.engine;
  this.subs.push(on(socket, 'data', bind(this, 'ondata')));
  this.subs.push(on(this.decoder, 'decoded', bind(this, 'ondecoded')));
  this.subs.push(on(socket, 'error', bind(this, 'onerror')));
  this.subs.push(on(socket, 'close', bind(this, 'onclose')));
};

/**
 * Called with data.
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.ondata = function(data){
  this.decoder.add(data);
};

/**
 * Called when parser fully decodes a packet.
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.ondecoded = function(packet) {
  this.emit('packet', packet);
};

/**
 * Called upon socket error.
 *
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.onerror = function(err){
  debug('error', err);
  this.emitAll('error', err);
};

/**
 * Creates a new socket for the given `nsp`.
 *
 * @return {Socket}
 * @api public
 */

Manager.prototype.socket = function(nsp){
  var socket = this.nsps[nsp];
  if (!socket) {
    socket = new Socket(this, nsp);
    this.nsps[nsp] = socket;
    var self = this;
    socket.on('connect', function(){
      socket.id = self.engine.id;
      if (!~indexOf(self.connected, socket)) {
        self.connected.push(socket);
      }
    });
  }
  return socket;
};

/**
 * Called upon a socket close.
 *
 * @param {Socket} socket
 */

Manager.prototype.destroy = function(socket){
  var index = indexOf(this.connected, socket);
  if (~index) this.connected.splice(index, 1);
  if (this.connected.length) return;

  this.close();
};

/**
 * Writes a packet.
 *
 * @param {Object} packet
 * @api private
 */

Manager.prototype.packet = function(packet){
  debug('writing packet %j', packet);
  var self = this;

  if (!self.encoding) {
    // encode, then write to engine with result
    self.encoding = true;
    this.encoder.encode(packet, function(encodedPackets) {
      for (var i = 0; i < encodedPackets.length; i++) {
        self.engine.write(encodedPackets[i]);
      }
      self.encoding = false;
      self.processPacketQueue();
    });
  } else { // add packet to the queue
    self.packetBuffer.push(packet);
  }
};
.....
```

**Socket.js**

```
    app.factory('socket', function(socketFactory){

        var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:3001');

        mySocket = socketFactory({
            ioSocket: socket
        });
        return socket;
    });
```

**Server Side**

```
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        cors = require('cors'),
        server = require('http').createServer(app),
        io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        users = {};
        var path = require('path');
    var gcm = require('node-gcm');
    var  fs = require('fs');
    var url = require('url');

      app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://"+req.headers.host+':3001');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    next();
    }
    );




     io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

      console.log('New User Connected to this server'); // This prints the content as soon as a client connects to the server.        

    socket.on('message', function(msg){
      console.log('message: ' + msg);  //This doesn't work and as well doesn't print any error message on the server console
    });
});
```

I cant seem to figure what is actually wrong, maybe I am not doing something right.

Extra information

```
 node.js v4.2.6
 express 4.15.3
 socket.io 1.7.3
```

Comment: On the client side. Can we make sure that `socket` is not undefined for `$scope.SendMessage`? It looks suspicious...

Comment: No please, that method works as it is supposed to

Comment: How did u check to make sure it is? The server code looks alright thou. Probably show us more of the client code.

Comment: Lemme show a different sheet of client side

Comment: @SamuelToh Script has been updated

Comment: `<script socket.io.js"></script>` This tag looks malformed to me... maybe you're missing the `src` attribute. Can you please double check it on the browser console and make sure there is no error?

Answer (score 1):

This answer has been updated, see EDIT part.

you can use a simple socket factory instead of using socketFactory :

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

And then use it like you did.

EDIT :

There are multiple things that I don't understand in your exemple :

Where do you include socket-io library in your html code ?

You are using Angular JS synthax in your socket.js file but don't use Angular JS and angular-js-io module.

With your exemple,I have two errors :

[image]

So first remove socket.js script, it won't work.
Include socket-io-client library with cdn or download it or serve it from your node js server, as you prefer. And it should work.

Comment: This as well connects to the server buh it doesn't emit data or either receives data from the server

Comment: I have added my socket.io.js to the main script

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that we start from this simple setup and only if it works try to complicate it ;)

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    users = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/george.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('New User Connected to this server'); // This prints the content as soon as a client connects to the server.
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);  //This doesn't work and as well doesn't print any error message on the server console
    });
});

server.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('listening on port 3001');
});
```

george.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
       <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
       <script>
           $(function () {
               var socket = io();
               $('form').submit(function(e){
                   socket.emit('message', $('#m').val());
                   $('#m').val('');
                   return false;
               });
           });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

1. you did not start the server with `server.listen`,
2. you did not load `socket.io.js` in the client,
3. you dont need `socket.js` at all